# How to map semi-colon then Esc to something other in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

How to set up AutoHotkey so that when I press semi-colon then Esc `;esc` in order, it will instead do something other?

`:?*:;Esc::
    msgbox, hello world
    ;; do something 
    ;; Send, {BACKSPACE} ;; remove the ; at last
return`

Answer (score 1):

I think you might not be able to do it with hotstrings, but instead with a regular hotkey. Also, I think you'll need to change the comment flag to something else that isn't a semicolon. Here's my attempt:

```
#CommentFlag //
~;::
KeyWait , Esc , DT2
If !ErrorLevel
{
    Send , {backspace}
    msgbox
}
Return
```